# How to test with Python's unittest that a warning has been thrown?

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, warnings

I have a following function in Python and I want to test with unittest that if the function gets 0 as argument, it throws a warning. I already tried assertRaises, but since I don't raise the warning, that doesn't work.

```
def isZero(i):
    if i != 0:
        print "OK"
    else:
        warning = Warning("the input is 0!") 
        print warning
    return i
```

Comment: Regarding working around *...if a warning has already been raised because of a once/default rule, then no matter what filters are set the warning will not be seen again unless the warnings registry related to the warning has been cleared.* ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#testing-warnings)) see [this article](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2013/06/26/testing-python-warnings/) about module level `__warningregistry__` (the registry docs mentions).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use the `catch_warnings` context manager. Essentially this allows you to mock the warnings handler, so that you can verify details of the warning. See the [official docs](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#testing-warnings) for a fuller explanation and sample test code.

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    # Cause all warnings to always be triggered.
    warnings.simplefilter("always")
    # Trigger a warning.
    fxn()
    # Verify some things
    assert len(w) == 1
    assert issubclass(w[-1].category, DeprecationWarning)
    assert "deprecated" in str(w[-1].message)
```

Comment: Take note that this is NOT thread safe, because it modifies a `global state` - if you use this in a test suite and other warnings are emitted, these will also show up in `catch_warnings`, which may cause false negatives.

Comment: Upvoted because example shows assertions for interesting properties - number, type, and message contents.

Answer (score 94):

Starting with Python 3.2, you can simply use [`assertWarns()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertWarns) method.

```
with self.assertWarns(Warning):
    do_something()
```

Comment: This works regardless of which warning filters are active. Therefore, I would use this answer rather than the accepted one.

Comment: Is there a similar way of asserting that a warning hasn't been triggered or would that require falling back on mocking or `warnings.catch_warnings`?

Comment: ... or running `self.assertWarns()` but sticking a `@unittest.expectedFailure` on the test.

Comment: where is the 'self' in self.assertWarns coming from?

Comment: @lightbox142 It is your testing class, a child of `unittest.TestCase`. If you are not familiar with it, you should read the page https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html from its beginning.

Answer (score 18):

You can write your own assertWarns function to incapsulate catch_warnings context. I've just implemented it the following way, with a mixin:

```
class WarningTestMixin(object):
    'A test which checks if the specified warning was raised'

    def assertWarns(self, warning, callable, *args, **kwds):
        with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as warning_list:
            warnings.simplefilter('always')

            result = callable(*args, **kwds)

            self.assertTrue(any(item.category == warning for item in warning_list))
```

A usage example:

```
class SomeTest(WarningTestMixin, TestCase):
    'Your testcase'

    def test_something(self):
        self.assertWarns(
            UserWarning,
            your_function_which_issues_a_warning,
            5, 10, 'john', # args
            foo='bar'      # kwargs
        )
```

The test will pass if at least one of the warnings issued by `your_function` is of type UserWarning.

Answer (score 7):

@ire_and_curses' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892218/how-to-test-with-pythons-unittest-that-a-warning-has-been-thrown/3892301#3892301) is quite useful and, I think, canonical. Here is another way to do the same thing. This one requires Michael Foord's excellent [`Mock` library](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/).

```
import unittest, warnings
from mock import patch_object

def isZero( i):
   if i != 0:
     print "OK"
   else:
     warnings.warn( "the input is 0!")
   return i

class Foo(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch_object(warnings, 'warn')
    def test_is_zero_raises_warning(self, mock_warn):
        isZero(0)
        self.assertTrue(mock_warn.called)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The nifty `patch_object` lets you mock out the `warn` method.

Comment: +1 - This solution is better than the accepted answer, as it does not use the global state of the `warnings` library - which may cause false negatives.

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, but the assertion in more recent versions of the mock library would be better this way, if you are not yet on Python 3 and can't use `assertWarns`: `mock_warn.assert_called_once()`. This would catch cases where some other random module unexpectedly raised a warning.

Comment: I'm just getting an error and can't find a proper reference: `    from mock import patch_object
ImportError: cannot import name 'patch_object' from 'mock' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mock/__init__.py)
` So I decided to use `with self.assertWarns(Warning):`

Answer (score 0):

One problem with the `warnings.catch_warnings` approach is that warnings produced in different tests can interact in strange ways through global state kept in `__warningregistry__` attributes.

To address this, we should clear the `__warningregistry__` attribute of every module before every test that checks warnings.

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    # The __warningregistry__'s need to be in a pristine state for tests
    # to work properly.
    for v in sys.modules.values():
      if getattr(v, '__warningregistry__', None):
        v.__warningregistry__ = {}

  def test_something(self):
    with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
      warnings.simplefilter("always", MySpecialWarning)
      ...
      self.assertEqual(len(w), 1)
      self.assertIsInstance(w[0].message, MySpecialWarning)
```

This is how Python 3's `assertWarns()` method is [implemented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d5fd75c53fad7049fc640c9a6162d35f0c5bea03/Lib/unittest/case.py#L245).

Answer (score 0):

Building off the answer from @ire_and_curses,

```
class AssertWarns(warnings.catch_warnings):
    """A Python 2 compatible version of `unittest.TestCase.assertWarns`."""
    def __init__(self, test_case, warning_type):
        self.test_case = test_case
        self.warning_type = warning_type
        self.log = None
        super(AssertWarns, self).__init__(record=True, module=None)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.log = super(AssertWarns, self).__enter__()
        return self.log

    def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
        super(AssertWarns, self).__exit__(*exc_info)
        self.test_case.assertEqual(type(self.log[0]), self.warning_type)
```

This can be called similarly to `unittest.TestCase.assertWarns`:

```
with AssertWarns(self, warnings.WarningMessage):
    warnings.warn('test warning!')
```

where `self` is a `unittest.TestCase`.

Answer (score 0):

Per Melebius' answer, you can use `self.assertWarns()`.

Additionally, if you want to check the warning message as well, you can use `self.assertWarnsRegex()` for that greater specificity:

```
import warnings
from unittest import TestCase


class MyCustomWarning(Warning):
    ...


def is_zero(i: int) -> int:
    if i != 0:
        print("OK")
    else:
        warnings.warn("the input is 0!", MyCustomWarning)
    return i



class TestIsZero(TestCase):

    def test_when_then_input_is_zero(self):
        regex = "the input is 0"
        with self.assertWarnsRegex(MyCustomWarning, expected_regex=regex):
            _ = is_zero(0)
```

This test will fail if the `regex` is not found in the warning message.